# Merging custom objects with structure similar to lists, using Python

Tags: python, merge, linked-list

I am trying to implement some kind of algorithm for my research paper(programming is not my major field of research) and I need some help. Consider following kind of data structure (e.g a and b) where we have a linear time line and objects placed on this time axis at certain distance from each other (actually these objects represent data packets whose width is equal to time needed to transmit the packet). I want to align them on right side, making it our reference point (time t=0) and then merge these two lists (a and b), if i may call them a list, and get a resulting list as shown in c. The overlapping objects are shifted to make single list and gap between these objects changes accordingly. Any idea how should I proceed? Linked lists? (if they exist in python). there can be more than two lists to be merged in a single list. Thanks in advance

```
       ____          _____            ____
    __| a3 |________| a2  |__________| a1 |  (a)

       ____             _____         ____
    __| b3 |___________| b2  |_______| b1 |  (b)


            ____  ____     ______  _____   ____  ____
    _______| a3 || b3 |___| a2   || b2  |_| a1 || b1 |  (c)
```

Comment: Are they aligned from right to left?

Comment: yes, they are aligned from right to left.

Comment: How to treat the collisions? For example, if a data packet from b couldn't fit between 2 successive data packets from a?

Comment: Also, if at same t there are data on a and b, in which order should the packets be concatenated?

Comment: depending upon the distance from our reference (that is right most side), first come first serve policy. I mean the packet which is closest to right most side should stay closer to the right most side after merging too. so we first put both data packets from a and then the one from b. or we put first packet from a then from b and then again from a by shifting packets of a towards right side, all depending on which one is closer to the right side as compared to the rest of packets having collisions. in case when both are exactly same distance away, then anyone can be placed first.

Comment: just to clarify a bit, as i have shown in my illustration, the middle packet from a and b overlap or collide with each other, so in resulting merged list c, packet from b is placed closer to right hand side (third packet from right side in c. 4th packet from right is middle packet of a). i will try to update illustration with packet numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example, dict for data items and lists for data sequences:

data 1:

**[{'start':0, 't': 10, 'dtype': 'a'}, {'start': 30, 't':20, 'dtype': 'a'}, {'start': 50, 't':30, 'dtype': 'a'}]**

data 2:

**[{'start':15, 't': 10, 'dtype': 'b'}, {'start': 40, 't':20, 'dtype': 'b'}, {'start': 50, 't':30, 'dtype': 'b'}]**

and merged list (sorted by start time):

```
sorted(data1+data2, key=lambda x:x['start'])
```

result:

**[{'start': 0, 't': 10, 'dtype': 'a'}, {'start': 15, 't': 10, 'dtype': 'b'}, {'start': 30, 't': 20, 'dtype': 'a'}, {'start': 40, 't': 20, 'dtype': 'b'}, {'start': 50, 't': 30, 'dtype': 'a'}, {'start': 50, 't': 30, 'dtype': 'b'}]**

For backorder use parameter 'reverse=True' in sorted function. To find overlapped elements you just check during list iteration if **item['start'] + item['t'] > nextitem['start']** ===> items overlapping, and you must adjust nextitem start position according your algorithm.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will check it and come back to share the result.

Comment: @ ndpu: I have tried your suggestion and it works. I do it like this:
        for item, nextitem in iterate_in_pair(result):
            while item['start'] + item['t'] > nextitem['start']:
                    nextitem['start'] = item['start'] + item['t']

That is, I must use a while loop to change 'start' of each element after the overlap, and it makes it slow, ( I have over 10000 such lists with large number of items in each list). Any efficient way to  do this? 
P.S. unrelated but I don't know why your answer is rated as "-1".